# Sum numbers in group and find the maximum number per group

Tags: sql, sql-server

For each individual ‘id’ I want to SUM(cc) based on ‘e_sour’

I then want to display each ‘id’ and find the maximum sum(cc) and its partnering ‘e_sour.’

With the code I have written, I can’t seem to  show individual ‘id’ in many cases it still shows multiple ‘id’ that are the same argh!

Data I have:

| id | e_sour | cc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | win | 400 |
| 1 | win | 400 |
| 1 | elec | 400 |
| 2 | win | 400 |
| 2 | win | 400 |

Output data:

| id | e_sour | cc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | win | 800 |
| 2 | win | 800 |

```
WITH Input1 AS
(
select id, e_sour, sum(cc) AS total_cc, rm
from  Prod
Group by id, e_sour, rm
Having rm = 'Latest'
), Input2 AS
(
Select  id, MAX(total_cc) AS max_total_cc, e_sour
From Input1
GROUP BY id, e_sour
), Input3 AS
(
Select  id, MAX(max_total_cc) AS max_total_cc2
From Input2
GROUP BY id
)
Select * 
from Input3
Inner join
(Select * from Input2) In2 ON Input3.id = In2.id
ORDER BY Input3.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you need a `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT id, e_sour, cc
FROM (  
   SELECT 
      id, e_sour, SUM(cc) AS cc, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY SUM(cc) DESC) AS Rn
   FROM Prod
   GROUP BY id, e_sour
) t
WHERE t.Rn = 1
```

Comment: awesome, this worked!!! That's a smart way= to go about it!